# How to write thread safe code in node.js

Tags: javascript, multithreading, node.js

Here's a part of my app.js:

```
var connections = [];

function removeConnection(res) {
    var i = connections.indexOf(res);
    if (i !== -1) {
        connections.splice(i, 1);
    }
}
```

And I call removeConnection when a request is closed:

```
req.on('close', function () {
    console.log("connection closed");
    removeConnection(res);
});
```

I wonder if the above code is thread safe? I mean as Node.js is event driven, is the following scenario possible?

1. connections is [a,b,c]
2. threadB calls removeConnection
3. in threadB.removeConnection: i = 1
4. threadA calls removeConnection
5. in threadA.removeConnection: i = 0
6. in threadA.removeConnection: connections.splice(0, 1); => connections is [b,c]
7. in threadA.removeConnection: connections.splice(1, 1); => connections is [b]

As you see in this scenario, threadC's connection would be removed instead of threadB's.

Can this happen? If yes, then how should I fix the code?

Comment: There's only a single thread in node.js apps so all node.js code is thread safe.

Comment: @JohnnyHK if that's so, then I would accept this as an answer. Is this something that might be changed in the future? Also adding more cores to a webserver that runs nodejs doesn't help it at all?

Comment: If you want to take advantage of more cores/processors, you can use [child processes](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options) manually or use something like the built-in [cluster module](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/cluster.html).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One of the key principles of Node.js is that all user code runs in a single thread which eliminates the need for the developer to deal with the complexities of writing thread-safe code.

So your code (and all Node.js code) is by definition thread-safe.

Comment: That doesn't mean Node.js does anything to eliminate race conditions. All that single JS thread does is ensure JS is always in a critical section.

Comment: @DavidEhrmann Sure it does. It means that any Node.js code will run to completion without any chance of being interrupted.  There is still the potential for race conditions when calling async methods, but that's a separate issue.