# Could this code cause race condition in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I'm working in Sails.js (v0.12.13), and one of my actions in the controller looks like:

```
create: function(req, res){

    var comment = req.body;

    var image_id = req.params.id;

    Image.findOne(image_id).populate('comments').exec(function(err, image){


        image.messages.add(comment);

        image.save(function(err){

            return res.created(comment);

        });
    });
}
```

(Error handling was ommited)

Basically this adds a `comment` to an `image`. First, I need to get the image, with it's comments, add the new comment to the array, and save it again.

However, my intuition is that there's a case when two different people try to add a comment, and the order of events is:

1. Request #1 does findOne() and becomes blocked
2. Request #2 does findOne() and becomes blocked
3. Request #1 adds a comment, executes save() and becomes blocked
4. Request #2 adds a comment, executes save() and becomes blocked
5. Both requests had the same original findOne() result, and they added their own comment, so when they save it, only the last one remains.

**Can this happen in Node.js?**, or is there something that prevents this from happening?

I've seen some examples in the website, like http://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/populated-values/add where they do something similar. If race condition can happen, then Sail.js becomes unuseable for me, because I find these things very important.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it would depend upon the specifics of the database.  If two requests to `Image.findOne()` return the exact same `image` object, then it would probably not be racy since they would each be modifying the same object and then saving it.  But, if they return different `image` objects, then it could cause a race condition for the reasons you theorize as object1 would get fetched, object2 would get fetched, object1 get modified and then saved, object2 modified, then saved, overwriting the changes made to object1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer**: Don't worry, you'll not lose / overwrite data this way.

---

> Can this happen in Node.js?

Yes

> is there something that prevents this from happening?

Yes

---

This condition is **not specific to Node.js** or asynchronous, event loop based execution.
Similar thing can happen with 2 threads handling 2 requests in other languages (Java, Ruby etc.) due to thread preemption.

### Problematic Implementation

1. Req#1 fetches Image and gets `{ id: 1, comments: [1, 2] }`
2. Req#2 fetches Image and gets `{ id: 1, comments: [1, 2] }`
3. Req#1 adds a comment so object becomes `{ id: 1, comments: [1, 2, 3] }`. On save, it ensures that only 1, 2, 3 comments are associated with Image 1.
4. Req#2 adds a comment so object becomes `{ id: 1, comments: [1, 2, 4] }`. On save, it ensures that only 1, 2, 4 comments are associated with Image 1, thereby **removing** comment 3

### Actual Implementation

1. Same as 1 above
2. Same as 2 above
3. Req#1 adds a comment so query object records `Comment#3` to be added. Something like `{ id: 1, comments: { value: [1, 2], addModels: [3] }`. On save, an association is created between `Comment#3` and `Image#1` in database.
4. Req#2 adds a comment so query object records `Comment#4` to be added. Something like `{ id: 1, comments: { value: [1, 2], addModels: [4] }`. On save, an association is created between `Comment#4` and `Image#1` in database. Earlier created association is `Comment#3` is **not touched**.

### Relevant code:

1. Waterline [association.js](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/blob/v0.11.9/lib/waterline/model/lib/association.js#L42)
2. Waterline [save.js](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/blob/v0.11.9/lib/waterline/model/lib/defaultMethods/save.js#L110)

Comment: I see! so that's why .add() is used instead of plain Array.push() method. It has some magic behind. That's incredible!

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/queries) state that :

> Query objects (aka query instances) are the chainable deferred objects
>   returned from model methods like .find() and .create(). They represent
>   a not-quite-yet-fulfilled intent to fetch or modify records from the
>   database.

So no, `findOne()` will not block. It all depends on the `exec()` method for the specific database engine. If the database driver has non-blocking API, then there will be no blocking. Race condition will also depend on the underlying DBMS implementation. But `findOne` will not cause a race condition.

Answer (score -1):

You're really asking if you code is thread safe, which in Node.js it is by default.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24785100/628601) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10020784/628601).

Your variables are all in their own functions and therefore in their own execution context or scope as well, so you're not changing any global (shared) variables.

Comment: No, that's not what the OP is asking.  Because they are using async operations, multiple requests can be getting processed interleaved with each other.

Comment: OP was asking about race condition, which will not happen as I stated in answer.

Comment: Race condition doesn't have to only apply to threads. In this case there is asynchronous and race condition can also happen. Even using a single event queue (like in JavaScript) does not prevent events coming in an undefined manner and your code should take care of this.

Comment: Chris, you are mistaken.  Depending upon the database, there could definitely be a race condition here and because of asynchronous operations that allow multiple requests to be interleaved, there could be two separate `image` objects being used where saving one would overwrite the changes saved from the other (thus a race condition).  See my comment to the OP's question for a little more info.

Comment: I get what you're saying, but this is more of a DB question and how the DB layer adds that comment to the DB.  If it does a full replacement of the document (NoSQL) then you're right, it will overwrite the document.  If it is using relational or if Waterline adapter uses $push() (in mongo) it should work fine (you'll get 2 new rows or 2 new elements).